# Unable to connect to databricks cluster from Windows using databricks-connect

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I am trying to setup databricks-connect in my windows machine. While doing databricks-connect test I am getting the below error complaining java certificate is not found. ''

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:271)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:275)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:140)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:630)
    ... 27 more                                                                          
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 33 more
```

I have java 1.8 installed and I downloaded the browser certificate and installed it
[image]

I installed the certificate using below command.

```
   keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias repo -file C:\Users\ravi\Downloads\adbcert.crt -keystore cacerts "C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
```

Still, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: most probably you have the web proxy in the middle that intercepts the SSL traffic. You need to get root certificate that is used by the web proxy and add it into the chain

Comment: Adding a root certificate solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding root certificate solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also check to see if:

```
encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
```

is in your connection string.  This was my issue.